# How do I pass Parameters in Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

How to receive parameters from firebase dynamic links in flutter?

I created a short url:

> https://subdomain.example.com/product

which points to

> https://example.com/view-product

But I want to add a url query parameter like:

https://example.com/view-product?id=56

Note that "56" is variable and changes dynamically inside app flow. I am unable to receive this "id" parameter.

On browser I tried entering https://subdomain.example.com/product?id=56

I received the link: https://example.com/view-product

```
     FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {

      final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

      showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context){
        return Container(
          height: 100.0,
          child: Text(deepLink.toString()),
        );
      });
      if (deepLink != null) {
        debugPrint("Link found on line: "+deepLink.queryParameters.toString());

      }
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
    });
```

Comment: You need to build your links as explained in the documentation.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I couldn't understand the documentation. Do I need to create the link on runtime? What should I do with firebase console?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Can you help sir? Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

I was understanding the concept totally wrong here.

There are 4 ways as of now to create dynamic links.

```
1) Firebase Console
2) Manually
3) Rest API
4) Dynamic Link Builder API on iOS and Android
```

What I was doing wrong here is was, I created https://subdomain.example.com/product a dynamic link from firebase console and was testing it against a manually created link.

2nd method(Manually) is much more powerful is you need to link dynamic content from your website links.

> https://your_subdomain.page.link/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&afl=fallback_link]

The above mentioned is the standard manual procedure for creating dynamic links.

Lets break down the above link so that it looks less scary:

- https://your_subdomain.page.link ==> This is simply your subdomain you registered on firebase console. In our case it's https://subdomain.example.com
- link=your_deep_link ==> your_deep_link is basically your deep link(the link you want to open with that exists on your server, it can contain all the parameters you need). In our case its https://example.com/view-product?id=56. But note that this link is to be embedded inside an url so it needs to be urlencoded first. Use any url encoder for this purpose. The resulting encoded string becomes

> https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fview-product%3Fid%3D56

- apn=package_name ==> your respective package name for IOS or Android
- [&amv=minimum_version] ==> "[]" represent this as an optional parameters. This parameter is the minimum version number of your app that you want your app should respond to this dynamic link (0 if you want all versions to support)
- [&afl=fallback_link] ==> ==> "[]" represent this as an optional parameters. This is the fallback url, again url encoded. Could be your android play store link.

So our final dynamic link looks like:

> https://subdomain.example.com/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fview-product%3Fid%3D56&apn=com.example&amv=0

Comment: It's powerful, but completely impossible to use for copy writers who need to use dynamic links in their content. they can't programmatically generate their URL's; I'll just about get them to understand adding the ID parameter to the URL prefix.

Comment: I wonder if I can use the REST API to generate the Dynamic Links as Articles are added to the Firestore?

Comment: @LeeProbert A simple JS function can also do it I think

Comment: @PushanGupta what will be the URL's on the firebase console?

Comment: For more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually

Comment: Dude, you are a god send! Thanks a lot.